# Unity Texture 2D from Uint64List bytes

Tags: string, flutter, unity-game-engine, byte, textures

I'm trying to generate a 2D texture from **Uint64List** bytes tried in a lot of ways, but nothing works :(

1. I'm getting the byte data from Image on my website like that:

   ```
   final ByteData data =
   await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(lastPosts.docs[0]['mediaUrl'][0]))
       .load(lastPosts.docs[0]['mediaUrl'][0]);
   ```

   final Uint64List bytes = data.buffer.asUint64List();
2. Sending and receiving in Unity as string and trying to generate a texture from byte data unsuccessfully, this way:

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fl_data))
            {
                byte[] imgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fl_data); //Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (inputString);
                Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
                tex.LoadRawTextureData(imgBytes);
                tex.Apply();

                m_screenTexture.texture = tex;
            }
```

or

```
            byte[] imgByte = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(byteTest);
            byte[] bytes2 = Convert.FromBase64String(byteTest);
```

I'm lost somebody can help me please, thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to upload image to server?

Comment: No, I have my image on server, I'm trying to generate Texture from byte[], thanks!

Comment: so you mean generate texture from byte[] on server? How did you upload byte[] to server?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by unsuccessfully? does it throw an error, does the texture end up being wrong, like just a black square, what exactly is happening?

Comment: I get this error:

UnityException: LoadRawTextureData: not enough data provided (will result in overread).
UnityEngine.Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData (System.Byte[] data) (at <f1212ad1dec44ce7b7147976b91869c3>:0)
RainPixels.UP_GameManager.GenerateImageFromBytesDebug () (at Assets/_RP/Scripts/UP_GameManager.cs:793)

Line 793:       tex.LoadRawTextureData(imgByte);